# How do I avoid RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED exceptions when performing PowerPoint automation?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, comexception

When my code tries to create a new instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application`, I sometimes get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010001): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
```

I say sometimes because it doesn't happen consistently even given the same input.  Furthermore, it also occurs (with the same lack of consistency) in other parts of my code where I also interact with the PowerPoint automation API.

I have tried out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) solution from MSDN itself which seems to be the most recommended solution out there.  However, it doesn't seem to have any impact as I still observe the same behavior.

My questions are:

1. Does the MSDN solution work for PowerPoint automation?
2. How can I verify whether I have correctly applied it to my code?
3. Does anyone have an alternative solution?

I am using C#, .NET 4, and PowerPoint 2007.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Maybe adding a Thread.Sleep(100) here and there should help? Filling a chart takes some time to update the grapics etc so you might have to wait for that before adding more data.

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this before and [Paul B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059776/paul-b) is indeed correct. It depends on whether you are calling the Powerpoint OM from the main thread (i.e. `This_AddIn`) or not. If you are, ppt should not throw these exceptions. However, if you are calling ppt from another thread, you must implement `IMessageFilter` to handle these windows message pump errors efficiently since ppt prioritizes main thread calls to the OM over calls from other threads, hence the call rejections.

There is another caveat that requires further boiler plate code to handle additional `COMException`s such as `0x800AC472 (VBA_E_IGNORE)`. There is an example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28680/is-brute-force-the-accepted-best-practice-for-handling-excel-com-busy-exceptio?noredirect=1#comment58978_28680).

So, the full solution is both to implement `IMessageFilter` and to use something like [sepp2k's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/583/23788) code in which to wrap your OM calls in order to handle other types of `COMException` that may be thrown.

So, for wrapping code like his:

```
private void TryUntilSuccess(Action action)
{
    bool success = false;
    while (!success)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            success = true;
        }

        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
        {
            if ((e.ErrorCode & 0xFFFF) == 0xC472)
            {   // Excel is busy
                Thread.Sleep(500); // Wait, and...
                success = false;  // ...try again
            }
            else
            {   // Re-throw!
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which you could call with lamdas like this:

```
TryUntilSuccess(() =>
{
    RegisterFilter(); // register this thread for IMessageFilter use
    ppt_app.DoSomething();        
    UnRegisterFilter(); // unregister this thread for IMessageFilter use
};)
```

The reason for this two-pronged approach is that the `IMessageFilter` strategy is more efficient than throwing exceptions and will more times than not be able to handle the busy messages coming from the app. However, at other times you will have to handle exceptions so you have to do both...

See here for the [IMessageFilter implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) which includes wrappers

Hth!

Comment: Just 'throw;' without the e for exception to re-throw without losing the stack trace.  [Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt620018.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 3):

1. I haven't tried it but Andrew Whitechapel describes the same approach for Office so I guess it should work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx
2. Give it a try :)
3. Another way would be to implement some sort of waiting mechanism by catching the error and retrying (also mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/e02a2999-b525-41af-9f47-a8b907c15817)).

Comment: Thanks, the first article you linked to explains `IMessageFilter` so well!